# How to convert working pandas code to a dask code?

Tags: pandas, dask

I have two dates in YYYMM format as

```
date1 = 203201
date2 = 201204
```

I have a dataframe [testdf] with 235 million rows which contains a date variable 'DATE_TO_COMPARE' that I need to compare with the above two dates for a filter.

I need to filter this dataframe as follows:

```
# Step 1: Create two date variables in the dataframe for comparison purposes
testdf['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['date1'], format = '%Y%m', errors='ignore')
testdf['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['date2'], format = '%Y%m', errors='ignore')

# Step 2: Apply the fiter
testdf_filtered = testdf[(testdf['DATE_TO_COMPARE'] <= testdf['date1']) & \
                   (testdf['DATE_TO_COMPARE'] > testdf['date2'])]
```

---

Problem is the above operations take 70 years to execute on 235 million rows :--)
So I recently realized, I have multiples cores on my PC, a sexy 5 cores lol. So, did some research and read about drumroll...DASK!

So here I am trying to daskize this code as follows:

```
# Daskize pandas dataframe
import dask as dd 
ddata = dd.from_pandas(testdf, npartitions=5)

# Step 1: Create two date variables in the dataframe for comparison purposes
ddata['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(ddata['date1'], format = '%Y%m', errors='ignore')
ddata['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(ddata['date2'], format = '%Y%m', errors='ignore')

# Step 2: Apply the fiter
ddata_filtered = ddata[(ddata['DATE_TO_COMPARE'] <= ddata['date1']) & \
                   (ddata['DATE_TO_COMPARE'] > ddata['date2'])]

# Re-Pandize Daskized dataframe
testdf_filtered = ddata_filtered.compute(scheduler='processes')
```

---

I obviously run into a host of errors in the dask code! Example:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment etc.
```

Any education/advise/example will be much appreciated. Thanks.